# In PHP I have an array which have 3 values. I want to store these 3 values in 3 variables

Tags: php

In PHP I have an array which have 3 values. I want to store these 3 values in 3 variables.

```
$my_values = array(5,6,7);
```

Comment: Have you made any effort or attempt to do this?

Comment: @ Qirel Yes.  foreach ($my_values as $val)
 {
    
 }

Comment: And what have you tried inside the loop? That's the essential part ;-)

Comment: First question - why? Is there a reason you can't just use the values directly from the array?

Comment: i get my answer. I were doing wrong.

Comment: @ iainn yes i can use this values directly from array. But i want to store these values in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[$x, $y, $z] = $my_values;
```

or

```
list($x, $y, $z) = $my_values;
```